# Pattern making tool illustrator. Adding fill to background tile

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, patterns

Is there a way to create a background fill for a repeat tile while editing a pattern making mode in illustrator?

Answer (score 1):

In pattern editing mode: Draw a rectangle, move it behind everything and add a fill.

---

Conversely, you can create your pattern *without* a background, then merely add a New Fill via the **Appearance Panel** for any object with the pattern applied.

[image]